# Next Song in MediaItemCollection?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

How do I find out the name of the next item to be played in an `MPMediaItem` collection?  I would prefer to store this as an `MPMediaItem`.

I have a `songsViewController` that has a `tableView` of all the songs.  This is my code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem;

    selectedItem = [[songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];

    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[songsQuery items]]];

    [musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:selectedItem];

    nowPlayingViewController *nowPlaying = [[rightSideMenuViewController alloc]
                                            initWithNibName:@"nowPlayingViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:nowPlaying animated:YES completion:nil];

    [musicPlayer play];

}
```

I have a `UILabel` on my `nowPlayingViewController` which pops up when the user has selected a song.  I would like to store the title of the next item in the `MediaItemCollection`/queue to be in that `UILabel` - so it is a preview of what the next song is.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!  :)

Comment: If you keep trace of the `MPMediaItemCollection` you may be able to use `[musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem]` to know which one is the next one.

Comment: How do I use that?  I've been trying a few things and I'm not sure I'm using it correctly :S

Comment: Save `[songsQuery items]`, that's an `NSArray`. Next music should be: `MPMediaItem *nextItem = [musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem]+1;`. Well, I didn't try and you may have to check if this index exists (I mean, if your nowPlayingItem is already the last one, etc. to avoid an out of bound error)

Comment: Yeah, I get two errors - 1) **Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'MPMediaItem *__strong' with an expression of type 'unsigned long** and 2) **Implicit conversion of 'unsigned long' to 'MPMediaItem *' is disallowed with ARC**

Comment: Could you show what you tried exactly?

Comment: I tried what you suggested :) - `MPMediaItem *nextItem = [musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem]+1;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53964/discussion-between-larme-and-user3127576)

Comment: My bad. `nextItem = [[songsQuery items] objectAtIndex:[musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem]+1];`

Comment: Thanks, but I have a smaller problem that I'd like to discuss in chat, if you're free, please?  It is related to this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your list (since your can't access at musicplayer queue).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *playlist;
```

When you do:

```
 [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[songsQuery items]]];
```

Add:

```
playlist = [songsQuery items];
```

To fetch your previous/next:

```
-(MPMediaItem *)nextItem
{
     int currentIndex = [musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem];
     MPMediaItem *nextItem = [playlist objectAtIndex:currentIndex+1];
     return nextItem
}

-(MPMediaItem *)previousItem
{
     int currentIndex = [musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem];
     MPMediaItem *previousItem = [playlist objectAtIndex:currentIndex-1];
     return previousItem;
}
```

**Important note:**
I didn't check if the current item was the first/last (according if you want previous/next) item in `playlist`. So be careful with bounds of the `NSArray`, or you'll get a:

```
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index Z beyond bounds [X .. Y]
```

So does `previousItem` "exists"? Does `nextItem` "exists"?

You may also have to look at:

```
@property (nonatomic) MPMusicRepeatMode repeatMode
```

In case that the `nextItem` may be the first item, or the previous item the last one.

Answer (score 0):

MPMusicPlayerController provides the following instance methods to quickly skip to your next or previous song:

```
[musicPlayer skipToNextItem];

[musicPlayer skipToPreviousItem];
```